# Showing Up Ratings on Another Store

Tags: multistore, review

I have the product reviews working on one store. Ratings are showing up, review details appears fine.
I have to show all the reviews on other store as well. So I created a shell script to set store.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getCollection();
$storeIds = array(1,2);
foreach ($collection as $review)
{
    $review->setStores($storeIds)->save()->aggregate();
}
```

Now the reviews are showing up, but the ratings are not.
Did I miss something on the code or I have to do this via admin?

Comment: Mate, I have the same question! Where did you put the code you created above?

Comment: I created a script to modify my products. The snippet above was added inside a `foreach ($productCollection as $product)` section of the script. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above is actually correct. It's the ratings settings. Rating for other stores is not enabled in the first place :D